# Remove directory from server that contains backslashes (PHP)

Tags: php, post, mkdir, rmdir

On my way to learning the `mkdir();` function in PHP, I have created a folder on my server with a path like so

```
 files/New\\\\
```

Now, I can not delete this for the life of me...
I found one other post that said I would need to use

```
 rmdir();
```

and escape the backslashes with more backslashes...

Needless to say, I can not get this to work... I had no idea that PHP added slashes through a post.  I know from here forth I should use `stripslashes();` but for now, I am stuck with two non deletable folders.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Log out of your FTP connection and log back in and try to delete it again, or login to your control panel on your server and delete the folders from the file manager.

Comment: have you tried using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of the '/'.

Comment: @MitchellLayzell I have done both... I use Yahoo for hosting and tried through the file manager on their site. Both ways failed, over and over.

Comment: @VIDesignz Try to rename it, then try to delete it.

Comment: @w3bMak3r No, I am unfamiliar with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` and how to implement it.  Can you show me an example of what I could try via php?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried that as well...keeps saying access denied/file may not exist.

Comment: I can not even delete parent folders if needed...

Comment: @VIDesignz does the folder exist on your server like www.yoursite.com/files/\\\ or just in your FTP folder?

Comment: @MitchellLayzell Yes, it comes up like this in my browser http://www.mysecretdomain.com/files/New\\\\/

Comment: Maybe you could write a script which uses scandir() and filter the resulting array for the string beginning with 'New'. Then pass this to rmdir().

Comment: @rantanplan Can you elaborate on that idea?

Comment: Try to use `exec('rm -rf FULPATHTOfiles');` but be sure that you properly escape \, ie each one `\ ` should be presented in string as `\\ `

Comment: Log in through ssh; type rm and the first few letters of the dir... Then hit tab for proper completion.

Comment: @JAL Your not speaking my language bro :(

Comment: @VIDesigns hopefully your language includes Google then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick'n'dirty script:

```
$filename = glob('../files/*');

foreach($filename as $file) {

    print "'". $file. "' ";
    if(strstr($file,'New')) {
        if(is_file($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
foreach($filename as $file) {
    if(strstr($file,'New')) {
        r_rmdir($file);
    }
}

function r_rmdir($dir) {
   if (is_dir($dir)) {
     $objects = scandir($dir);
     foreach ($objects as $object) {
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") r_rmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
       }
     }
     reset($objects);
     rmdir($dir);
   }
```

}

Comment: Maybe you have to adapt the path used in glob(). It depends of course of where your script is seated...

Comment: I have the path right, I have other functions working properly off that particular page that manipulate that `files` folder. Granted, I deleted the other functions for now until I figure this out.

Comment: Is there a New* dir printed if you output $file?

Comment: Yes, 3 of them (was testing) `'files/New' 'files/New\\\\' 'files/New\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'`

Comment: Ok thats good- Problem is, that they are not empty. Combine my script with the one from Mitchell... (Deletes the files inside first)

Comment: Genius!! This one is snippet worthy!

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

This should remove all the folders and files you have created for both directories, just run this script and it should remove them both completely

**PHP**

```
rmdir("../files/New\\\\/thumbnail");
rmdir("../files/New\\\\");

$filename = glob('../files/New\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/*');

foreach($filename as $file) {

    if(is_file($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
rmdir("../files/New\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/thumbnail");
rmdir("../files/New\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
```

**2.**

Have you tried renaming the folder with php? Like, so

**PHP**

```
$oldname = '../files/New\\\\';

$newname = '../files/please';

rename($oldname, $newname);
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, though I tried both ways with no success.

Comment: Dang haha this is bugging me now haha

Comment: Have you tried creating another folder with the same name in the same directory?

Comment: Just did, have a look http://www.videsignz.com/sandbox/uploader/server/php/files/

Comment: @VIDesignz you have files in the folders you will have to empty those folders first before you can delete the folder so I'll update my first example, one sec.

Comment: Woah, The renaming script on its own deleted the plain `../files/new` folder.

Comment: Hmm, can you create an FTP account and give it access to the parent folder and e-mail me the login to mitchlayzell@gmail.com and I'll try to delete it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39546/discussion-between-videsignz-and-mitchell-layzell)